# Method from subclass is not found in superclass

Tags: java

I have a Cube class created with a method designed to take in a String value:

```
public Cube()
{
    super();
}

public Cube(int side)
{
    this.side = side;
}

public Cube(String color)
{
    this.color = color;
}
```

I have a setter method created in another subclass which my Cube class extends

```
public void setColor()
{
    this.color = color;
}
```

When I use the setColor(Cube.Cube(RED)); method, I am getting a compiling error and a RuntimeException. The IDE is saying it cannot find the Cube(String) symbol in the Cube class.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

EDIT:
The RED variable I am using is initialized as:

```
final static String RED = "red";
```

My end goal is to set the color of the object based on user input. This is for a school project though, so I was hesitant on posting the entire code. I didn't want to have that interfere with what I am trying to accomplish with this method. This is a beginner level Java class I am in, so I am using switch statements for the user input. Should the user enter "red", I am trying to call this method to set the cube's color to red.

```
static void addCubeColor()
{
    String userColor;
    System.out.println("Please enter the cube's color: ");
    userColor = input.nextLine();

    switch(userColor.toLowerCase())
    {
        case RED : setColor(Cube.Cube(RED));
                   break;

        case GREEN : setColor(Cube.Cube(GREEN));
                     break;

        case BLUE : setColor(Cube.Cube(BLUE));
                    break;

        default : setColor(Cube.Cube(RED));
                  break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an exception *and* a compilation error, that suggests you're trying to run the code despite it not compiling. Don't do that. Next, it's not clear what you expect the expression `Cube.Cube(RED)` to mean... did you just mean `Cube.RED`? Finally, it would really help if you'd just provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem rather than snippets. It's not at all clear whether the problem has *anything* to do with subclasses, or whether it's really just that you haven't referred to your constant properly.

Comment: That setColor method looks odd. Are you sure it doesn’t have a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Your setColor method should take a parameter, one of the same type that your color variable is, and then use that parameter to set the color. Yours doesn't.

e.g.,

```
public void setColor(ColorType color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

Where ColorType is the type for the color variable. For example, if this were AWT or Swing, ColorType would be `java.awt.Color`.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I didn't catch that at all!

Still getting the compiling error though. NetBeans is saying it's still unable to locate the symbol (method Cube(String) in the Cube location) though.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It should also be "Cube.RED" as your parameter, I believe. You pass in static variables as [Class name they're in].[static variable name], so in this case, "Cube.RED".

Looks like the error is because you're trying to pass an argument to setColor(), but the method doesn't take any parameters. Changing it to

```
public void setColor(String color)
{
    this.color = color;
}
```

Should fix it.

Comment: Well, that's *one* error. Another is using `Cube.Cube(RED)` as an expression. Given that we've only seen a few snippets of code, I wouldn't be surprised if there were other issues.

Comment: There may be other errors in the code that I am not able to see, however, the program builds and my IDE doesn't display any other errors aside from this one.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting on the line `setColor(Cube.Cube(RED));` means that the compiler is looking for the static function named `Cube`. It looks like what you're trying to achieve is

`setColor(new Cube(RED));`

Answer (score 0):

`public Cube(String color)` is not a method but a constructor. To call it, you must use `new Cube(color)` but be aware that it will create a new instance of `Cube`.

If you objective is to change the color of an existing cube, you have to call your `setColor` method on the instance.
For example:

```
final Cube cube = new Cube(RED); // A new red cube
cube.setColor(BLUE); // cube is now blue
```

For this to work, your `setColor` method should take a `String color` argument:

```
public void setColor(String otherColor) {
    this.color = otherColor;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was worried about. The cube is already created prior to running this code, so I am trying to assign the color value to the already created object.

Comment: You should be able to change the color with `cube.setColor(<your new color here>);`.
If `setColor` does not exists on `Cube` and if you can't modify the `Cube` class, you should create a new `Cube` with the different color and use it instead of the old one.